# jquery calculate percentage with a max of 100%

Tags: jquery

Simple progress bar that shows the percent the user has scrolled down a particular section of the page, in this case the main body of an article page (.post), reaches 100% when the end of the article/beginning of the comments are reached.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var conheight = $('.post').height();
    var startDistance = 0;
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollArea = $('.commentswrapper').offset().top - $('.post').offset().top;


    // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page and substract comment section
    var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / (scrollArea); 

    if (scrollTop > 0) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', scrollPercent +"%"  );
    } else {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', startDistance);
    }

});
```

The problem is that although it reaches 100% when the end of .post is reached, it keeps expanding as the comment section is scrolled.

How do I limit scrollPercent to 100% as an maximum?

Comment: So only do the scrolling stuff if the % is less than 100%?

Comment: Ah yeah, i guess that'd be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Occam's razor I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page and substract comment section
var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / (scrollArea);

if (scrollPercent > 100) {
    scrollPercent = 100;
}
```